# Running Script from module in Ipython

Tags: python, terminal, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a class for some data analytics stuff that I use in the terminal to launch some generic visualizations, and I've spent three hours now trying to find the docs for how to run a script from the IPython module. I know there's a way to run magics like below, but these docs are the most inadequate thing I've ever seen in tech. Like not even docstrings for half the ****. Does anybody know how to do something similar with either the current terminal instance or by launching another? Either would work, I just need to be able to call this class from the terminal, and have the class execute something in any terminal...

```
from IPython import get_ipython
ipython = get_ipython()
ipython.magic("%matplotlib backend osx")
```

**To be clear, this is wrong but generally what the goal is:**

```
from IPython import get_ipython

class VizStuff:
   def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

   logsFilesGraphsAndwhatnot...

   def mito(self):
      ipython = get_ipython()
      newInstance = ipython.launchNewTerminalInstance()
      newInstance.runCommand('jupyter lab')
      mitosheet.sheet(dfte=self.DataFrame)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a much simpler script and then work up from there. Save a very simple **PURE python** text script, such as `print("Hello world"), as something like `mytest.py` in the directory that comes up when you type `pwd` in your IPython console. Then to run that script, in the IPython console enter `%run mytest.py` and hit return. When working back up to more complicated, try other magics. The Matplotlib backend stuff is a bit complex. For example, I'm not sure `osx` is the right syntax? Maybe it is but [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/users/explain/backends.html) says something different.

Comment: Also, for a related but different approach, when using IPython on the command line to run a script, you can save the extension as `.ipy` and actually use IPython magic commands as lines in the script just as you would in a Jupyter notebook, such as the `%store` magic command. (The `.ipy` extension in combination with running with IPython also allows you to use the exclamation point in front of shell commands in an ipython script, too.)  So you'd run such a script from the command line as `ipython mytest.ipy`.